# Writing a method with char input and char output

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method which assigns a complementary DNA base to another one.

Here is what I have for now:

```
public class DnaTest {
  public static void main(String[] args){

 }

    public static boolean aGoodBase (char c) {                
    boolean aBase;

    if (c == 'A' || c == 'G' || c == 'C' || c == 'T') 
    {
      aBase = true;     
    } 
    else 
    {
      aBase = false;
    }
    System.out.println(aBase);
    return aBase;

  }

    public static char baseComplement (char c){
    boolean anotherBase = isGoodBase(c);



    if (anotherBase)
    { 
      if (isGoodBase('A')) 
      {
        c = 'T';
      }

      else if (isGoodBase('T')) 
       {
        c = 'A';
       } 

      else if (isGoodBase('G'))
       {
        c = 'C';
       }

      else if (isGoodBase('C'))
       {
        c = 'G';
       }

      System.out.println(c);
      return c;
    }

    else
    {
      System.out.println(c);
      return c;
    }

  }
}
```

The second method should first verify if the inputted character is a valid base (A C G or T) by using the first method and then assign its complementary base (if the base is not valid, it should just print out the same character e.g. input Z, output Z).

With this code, i get the following output when I input 'A':

```
true
true
true
T
```

But I get the exact same output if I input another base ...

And when I input a non-valid base such as 'z', I get:

```
false
false
z
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Hint: a switch statement would be a much simpler way of solving this problem. Next, note that you're calling `if (isGoodBase('A'))` etc - those calls don't depend on the value of `c` at all...

Comment: BTW: aGoodBase - isGoodBase

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I am not allowed to use a switch statement unfortunately, I will change my code according to what you just told me and edit my post. Thank you !

Comment: Forbidding the use of constructs that are less error-prone is a deplorable education technique.

Answer (score 0):

In the code that determines the complementary base, you are writing:

```
if (isGoodBase('A')) {
    c = 'T';
}
```

When you should be writing:

```
if (c == 'A') {
    c = 'T';
}
```

You have already checked that the base `c` was a correct base (because we are in the case when `anotherBase` is `true`) so you don't need to check it again.

You can rewrite this more easily with a [switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

```
switch (c) {
case 'A': c = 'T'; break;
case 'T': c = 'A'; break;
case 'C': c = 'G'; break;
case 'G': c = 'C'; break;
}
```

Comment: I can't use a switch statement but I have applied the changes in the if statements and now the correct base is printed. But i still get the boolean value printed two times ... why is that ?

Comment: @Jayzpeer In your post, you are missing the code inside the `main` method. Maybe you are calling `isGoodBase` inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Less code - less chance for errors.

```
public static char baseComplement (char c){
    int index =  "ATGC".indexOf( c );
    if( index >= 0 ){
        return "TACG".charAt( index );
    } else {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Using final static Strings for the literals is highly recommended.